# Java 8 stream group list by multiple attributes

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of items. I would like to group this list by 3 attributes (category, color, city).

Example :

```
ID;Category;Color;City;Name
1;1;Red,Rome,Shoe A
2;1;Red,Paris,Shoe C
3;1;Green,Rome,Scarf
4;1;Red,Rome,Shoe B
5;2;Red,Rome,Scarf
6;1;Red,Rome,Scarf
7;1;Green,Rome,Shoe
```

So that in the end I have a list like the following :

```
1;Red;Rome => ID (1,4, 6)
1;Red;Paris => ID(2) 
1;Green,Rome => ID(3,7)
2;Red;Rome => ID(5)
```

I know how to group the list by an attribute :

```
Map<Category, List<Items>> _items = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getCategory()));
```

But how do I do this with multiple attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object that will serve as a key that identifies uniquely a tuple made of the 3 values `Category`, `Color` and `City`. Something like this :

```
public class Key {
  private final int category;
  private final String color;
  private final String city;

  public Key(int category, String color, String city) {
    this.category = category;
    this.color = color;
    this.city = city;
  }

  //Getter

  public static Key fromItem(Item item) {
    //create the key from the item
    return new Key(item.getCategory(),...)
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (this == o) return true;
     if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
     Key key = (Key) o;
     return category == key.category && color.equals(key.color) && city.equals(key.city);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
     return Objects.hash(category, color, city);
  }
}
```

You can then use your line of code with a simple modification :

```
Map<Key, List<Items>> _items = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Key::fromItem));
```